# Sync network-drive (Windows Home Server 2011)

Tags: networking, server, nautilus, mount, sync

I'm running a WHS 2011 NAS in my network and I'd like to auto-sync several folders (e.g. music) every once in a while. To do so, I used to use "Create Synconicity" on Windows.

On Ubuntu 12.10 I'm unable to do so. Neither grsync nor FreeFileSync enable me to select the network-drive.

The drive/NAS is mounted via Nautilus and displayed under "Network", yet this tab doesn't appear in grsync/FreeFileSync.

Has anyone a suggestion for me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I might share some knowledge here.

1. Determine machine's IP (using the machine's name in the Windows-network won't do the job)
2. If necessary, start the server via Wake-On-Lan, w.g. via a RDP, ping or similar (I've been using a WHS Addin called "Lights Out" which basically is a WoL-service which uses a Windows client-software to automatically boot the server as you start the client-PC... not available for Linux, though. So this is just a workarround.)
3. Mount the drive

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/shared
   sudo mount -t cifs "//192.168.0.xxx/Exchange" /mnt/shared/ -o user=User
   ```
4. Simply use a preferred syncing-tool like grsync and use the created mount-dir
   (Or use the regular rsyn-command)

   ```
   rsync /dir /mnt/shared -u -P -z
   ```

I've put all the commands in a script which I simply start manually every once in a while, but I'm sure you can make this happen automatically somehow. But the main reason why it refused to work was the fact that the drive wasn't mounted via cifs.